# Invoke methods and pass arguments between child iFrame and PhoneGap app on iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

If we include an iFrame in our PhoneGap app, is it possible to "forward" plug-in calls from the main app to the iFrame?

For instance, if we want to pass arguments to the iFrame from callback functions invoked by the In-App-Purchase plug-in, is this possible?

Or if we want to invoke a plug-in method from the iFrame, is this possible? Meaning, we need to invoke a plug-in function and pass it arguments from the iFrame.

The `postMessage` method is insufficient since it doesn't appear to allow the passing of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.

I would not recommend iframes in your phonegap app. Are you sure they are needed? There are some rather hacky ways to do what you are asking with the InAppBrowser, especially if you have control over the site you are loading into the InAppBrowser, but if I were you I would reconsider your problem and solution altogether.